# Choosing a column in my dataframe to create line chart

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

My data set has three columns.  One column for time, and two other columns for temperature measurements (Temp1, Temp2).

I want to be able to select Temp1 or Temp2 and graph the time series, but I am not sure how to do that in my server.R code.  What should go in my dygraph function call?

```
# This is the server logic for a Shiny web application.
# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
# http://shiny.rstudio.com
#

library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$TempData <- renderDygraph({
    data <- switch(input$data,
                   "Temp 1" = Data1$Temp1,
                   "Temp 2" = Data1$Temp2),
    dygraph(data, main = "Temperature Rise Data") %>%

     **I'm not sure what goes in here** 

  })

})
```

and here is ui.R

```
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application.
# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
# http://shiny.rstudio.com
#

library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Temperature Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("data", label = "Choose a Dataset",
                  choices = c("Temp 1", "Temp 1"),
                  selected = "Temp 1" ))
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("TempData")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Is your input data an xts object or can it be converted to an xts object? Your general approach seems correct but it's hard to tell what you're missing without a full reproducible example.

Comment: The input data is not an xts object.  It was read in through read.xlsx.  Can this be converted to an xts object, or should I just use a normal line chart?

Comment: You can convert it. Could you please run `dput(Data1)` and include the output as part of your question - that will help me to help you.

Comment: `Data...60.13, 60.027, 59.911, 59.905, 59.85, 59.747, 59.695, 59.605, 
59.57, 59.447, 59.373)), .Names = c("Scan", "Temp1", "Temp2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1645L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I still don't really know what your 'time' data looks like, what is the current data type of your `Scan` variable?

Comment: It's just a column consisting of numbers 1 through 1645.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, this should give you something along the lines of what you're looking for?

I'm forcing the coercion of `Scan` to a `Date` in order to make it compatible - not sure if this is the best way of doing this, but it will at least allow you to generate basic dygraphs with this data for the moment - you'll probably want to look into formatting the axis further.

```
...
data <- switch(input$data,
               "Temp 1" = as.xts(Data1$Temp1, order.by = as.Date(Data1$Scan))
               "Temp 2" = as.xts(Data1$Temp2, order.by = as.Date(Data1$Scan))
dygraph(data, main = "Temperature Rise Data")
...
```

Comment: That works!

I also renamed "data", because it was confusing R and giving me a weird error.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem - glad I could help!